# How do I get user's local date and time in RESTful app with Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, rest, spring-mvc, locale

I have a app where the user is able to perform actions, but only once and if his local time is before noon. The question is how can I retrieve this from user?
Say I have a method in the controller like this:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/performaction")
 public void performIt()
 {
   if(/*somehow getHour()*/ < 12)
   {
     perform();
   }
   else reject();
  }
```

I know that JS can help out, by calling `var date = new Date()` I can retrieve it, but I don't have any JSP pages to put this code and get locals. The service is completely REST with plain text. How can I do that?

Comment: `new Date()` is not reliable in Javascript anyway, it depends on the device date/time settings, which can be changed, so i hope this is not for securing something. I guess the only way would be to find the user's locale and ask a service which time it is there (or calculate it if you want your server to be the reference time, assuming it has the right one)

Comment: Taking local time of server will not work as server can be in different timezone. If you want to deal with only current time then accept timezone of user and calculate time depending on timezone. If only current time is not the case then accept the epoc format of time and timezone and convert same epoc to required timezone accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use java8's LocalTime.now() and do compare like this

```
  LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now(); 
    LocalTime noon= LocalTime.of(12, 0); 

    if(currentTime.isBefore(noon){
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the time stamp from the server itself if you can ignore the network time in your use-case.